Is Kruskal-Wallis really a good test of stochastic superiority?
After much reading/googling, I reached the conclusion that the Kruskal-Wallis test (K-W) is a test of stochastic superiority (or, equivalently, of stochastic equivalence). Rejecting the null implies that at least 1 population is stochastically superior to at least another 1 (E.g. from Wikipedia, "A significant Kruskal–Wallis test indicates that at least one sample stochastically dominates one other sample".)
One interesting property of stochastic superiority is the fact that this is not a transitive property.
So, for fun (?), I created 4 samples from Efron's dice (non-transitive!). I replicated the values 6 times, for a sample size of 48 each. To avoid so many ties, I added to each a small amount of gaussian noise ($N(0,.1)$).This gave me the 4 samples below 
I then ran a Kruskal-Wallis test on these 4 samples. The p-value was 0.974. Certainly not significant...
I also ran the Dunn MCT, which said that there were no significant group differences (of course, given the p-value).
I then ran all 6 Mann-Whitney U tests. I used Sidak's MCC, which gave me an adjusted $\alpha'=0.0085$ for 6 comparisons (0.00833 for Bonferroni). Sample A was stochastically superior to B, which was superior to C, which was superior to D, which was superior to A (as we would expect from Efron's dice). The other 2 (A-C and B-D) showed no significance. For all the significant M-W U tests, the p-value was $0.005 < 0.0085$).
This leaves me with a non-significant K-W, even though there are 4 significant M-W U. Which do you believe? (I know I believe the M-W U tests, fwiw)
I know that, hand-wavingly speaking, the K-W test's statistic is akin to an F test, but on ranks. But by "blurring" the groups together, does it not lose the specific shape differences of the various samples, which made them stochastically different?
Does that mean that K-W is NOT a good omnibus test of stochastic superiority? Then what does it test?
Updated 4/23/2024
I ran a few more tests.

First a K-W with just the first 2 samples (A & B). p=0.005 (Just like M-W U, as expected.
Then a K-W with the first 3 samples (A, B & C). p=0.456 (?)
So K-W told me that there was a difference between A & B (note: I do not specify what the difference is, on purpose: stochastic superiority, median, distribution, ???. But there was a difference between A & B). However, when I add a 3rd sample, this significant difference disappears?
Thinking that maybe K-W loses power when more groups are added (??), I quadrupled the sample size to 192 per group. Re-ran K-W on these 4, and got p=0.828. The M-W U between A & B (e.g.) gave p=0.000000016
Then, trying to see if the inability of K-W to find significance was because of the non-transitivity of stochastic superiority, I kept samples A & B at a size of 198, but dropped C&D (which contain non-transitive values) at 48. This new K-W test gave a p-value of 0.007. Finally!

What is happening with K-W? And why?
Updated 4/24/2024
After digging around a bit more, I came around this very informative paper "Kruskal–Wallis, Multiple Comparisons and Efron Dice", Bruce M. Brown and Thomas P. Hettmansperger https://api.semanticscholar.org/CorpusID:55698326 which explains the situation very well.
The issue has to do with the non-transitive property of stochastic superiority. When there are such non-transitive situations (the authors call these "circularities", but to me that gives the wrong image, so I will stick with the cumbersome "non-transitivities"), the power of the K-W test diminishes, sometimes dramatically, like in the example of my question.
I doubt that "non-transitivities" need to be of the extreme "rock/paper/scissors" type as I used in the original question. I think they can be much more subtle, as in the example below: we have 3 samples A,B & C (5 samples each).[![K-W counter example][2]][2]
Because the sample size is (very) small, one can directly look at all the pair-wise comparisons. A "beats" B 23 out of 25 times, and B "beats" C 20 out of 25 times. One would expect A to beat C handily? But this occurs (only) 20 out of 25 times. A strict transitivity property has not been respected. The 2-sample K-W test (A,B) was significant (p=0.028), but the 3-sample K-W test (A,B,C) gives p=0.061.

What type of stochastic dominance are you interested in?

The same one used for M-W U, or the original Efron's dice, namely $P(X_A>X_B)>.5$. A randomly selected value from population A will be greater than a randomly selected value from population B more than 50% of the time.

That's not stochastic dominance, which is $\forall x, F_A(x) \leq F_B(x)$ with strict inequality for at least one $x$.

That is exactly why I called it stochastic superiority! (and not dominance) @Galen used the term "dominance". Wikipedia also used the term, but I did not... And K-W test does not demonstrate  dominance (of the first order, which is the definition you gave), it demonstrates superiority, according to the definition I gave... It is trivial to create counter-examples of significant K-W (or MW-U) tests, where $F_A(x)$ is not $<= F_B(x)$ for all  x's.

That's fair enough, @jginestet. Thank you for defining the term "stochastic superiority".

@Galen, thanks. Note also that type 1 stochastic dominance is transitive. There is no way to get the "rock/paper/scissors" situation I describe in the question. If A dominates B, and B dominates C, then A will dominate C. But if A is superior to B, and B is superior to C, A is not automatically superior to C (that is the very case of the Efron's dice")

Not an answer to this question, but I feel like this answer provides an interesting approach to studying stochastic ordering that is sensitive to violations of transitivity. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/641857/69508

Also related to stochastic superiority: https://galenseilis.github.io/posts/dist-min-greater-than-max/

That is not what K-W tests for.  It tests, most generally, that all assignments of $n_1$ ranks to treatment 1 observations, all assignments of $n_2$ ranks to treatment 2 observations, etc. are equally likely.   If we make stricter assumptions, which your example does not satisfy, we can turn it into a test of equality of medians, but to do so, we have to assume all the distributions are the same except for the location of their medians (i.e., the treatment effect only affects the median.)

@jbowman, of course it is a test of the mean ranks, but this is not interpretable. I quote from the Talk page on wikipedia "The Kruskal-Wallis test is, in its most general application, a test of the null hypothesis that there is no stochastic dominance between any of the groups tested (i.e. H0: P(Xi > Xj) = 0.5 for all groups i and j, with HA: P(Xi > Xj) ≠ 0.5 for at least one i ≠ j). ". Now this author uses the term "dominance" which leads to confusion with formal definitons of "stochastic dominance". I use the term "superiority" to avoid this misunderstanding....

.... The reason it is a test of stochastic superiority (just as MW-U) is because the K-W test statistic can be expressed as a function of the sum of all paired differences of each group against all the other groups. A significant statistic means that at least 1 group is "superior" to at least another... Now that is interpretable (pick the superior one). But the 2 formulations of the K-W statistic are 100% exchangeable: if the mean ranks differ significantly, this is because one group's values are significantly more often greater than the other's.

The authors' statement is incorrect, although it's a not-uncommon misperception.  It is trivially easy to construct examples where there is nothing close to stochastic dominance, yet KW (correctly) rejects the null almost all the time, even with moderate sample sizes.   Nonetheless, the finding about transitivities is interesting, and I've learned something (+1)!

@jbowman, I am not talking about stochastic "dominance", but superiority. One is F($X_a$)<=F($X_B$) (cdf of A<cdf of B) for all x. The other is $P(X_A)>P(X_B)$>.5. Stochastic superiority is exactly the same as (mean ransk of A)>(means ranks of B). There is an deterministic relation betrween the M-W U statistic, and the K-W H statistic (see "Kruskal–Wallis, Multiple Comparisons and Efron Dice",
B.M. Brown, T.P. Hettmansperger, Australian & New Zealand Journal of Statistics, 44: 427-438.

I explicitly referred to the authors' statement, not yours.  Furthermore, the Wikipedia quote in your first paragraph makes the same claim about KW and stochastic dominance, and the quote you refer to a few comments above also incorrectly uses the phrase "stochastic dominance."  As a point - it's better not to bring inconsistent and incorrect definitions from other sources into the discussion, especially if they are also irrelevant to the question.

I do agree that terminology here is very loose, and leads to confusion. Mann&Whitney called "stochastically larger", I have seen and adopted "stochastic superiority", some, as you noted, use "stochastic dominance", and I even read someone calling it "0th order stochastic dominance". Unfortunate...

For example, this description of a R function for a Dunn test: "Computes Dunn's test (1964) for stochastic dominance and reports the results among multiple pairwise comparisons after a Kruskal-Wallis test for 0th-order stochastic dominance among k groups (Kruskal and Wallis, 1952)."

The original paper by Mann and Whitney call it "stochastically larger" and a seminal paper on the test by Fay et al. calls this "stochastic ordering" (see perspective 2).

I don't like to spend much time with special cases, and for the multi-group problem I use the generalization of the K-W test, the proportional odds ordinal logistic semiparametric model.  The model also exposes what is going on with regard to transitivity, in a way.  To get the K-W test (actually a better version of it that handles ties better and allows for covariate adjustment) one puts $k-1$ indicator variables in the model for $k$ groups.  An example is here.  When you translate the resulting odds ratios to concordance probabilities the transitivity problem persists.  But when viewing effects on the scale of logit of exceedance probabilities, i.e., $\text{logit}(\Pr(Y \geq y))$ as the proportional odds model is originally stated, you'll see that the group effects on this scale are transitive.
Thus transitivity is a transformation-dependent idea.
