Appropriate way to correct for multiple comparisons in this case
I am trying to compare the performance of an optimisation algorithm on different objective functions. The functions can vary in their form (4 different types) and dimension. I would like to first check if there are any differences between performance for those 4 different type in any dimension.
I can first check the results for one dimension with Kruskal–Wallis test and then analyse the specific pairs for that dimension with either Conover–Iman test or Dunn's test. But what if I do this for many dimensions? How to correct all of those test for multiple comparisons?
I thought of pooling the data from all dimensions but then some small difference that are only present in higher or lower dimensions might be diluted and not be detected.

Can you treat each combination of function/dimension as an independent category? Then you can use a single omnibus test to test them all, with MCC. You also mention K-W test; I will assume that is because your samples do not look "normal". But it is not the sample which need to be normally distributed, but the residuals. Also note that K-W is NOT a test of location, but of stochastic superiority, and has some "odd" behavior (i.e. non-transitive: e.g. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/645594/is-kruskal-wallis-really-a-good-test-of-stochastic-superiority) ...cont

I would at least try a 1-way ANOVA, using the Welch variant which does not require homoscedasticity and honestlky should be used all the time), and see what the residuals look like. If they are not too ugly, you will have your answer.

@jginestet Thanks!
